# Can I delete a specific value within a section of a config.ini file using Python configparser?

Tags: python, config, ini, configparser

I have a config.ini file and I am trying to delete a specific value in a section of my config.ini file. I basically want to delete an index within a list. The ***config.ini*** file is:

```
[INPUT]
intervals = [[4000, 6000], [25000, 55000]]
```

For example, I want to delete `[4000, 6000]`, so that the new ***config.ini*** file becomes:

```
[INPUT]
intervals = [[25000, 55000]]
```

My code is below with two functions, one to import the contents of config.ini (`load_args()`) and another to delete a section of config.ini (`delete_args()`). The delete function is based off an answer to [How to remove a section from an ini file using Python ConfigParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37265888/how-to-remove-a-section-from-an-ini-file-using-python-configparser)

```
import configparser
import ast

def load_args():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    interval = ast.literal_eval(config['INPUT']['intervals'])
    print(interval)

load_args()

def delete_args():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    with open('config.ini', 'r+') as s:
        config.readfp(s)  
        config.remove_section('INPUT')
        s.seek(0)
        config.write(s)
        s.truncate()
        interval = ast.literal_eval(config['INPUT']['intervals'])
        print(interval)

delete_args()
```

The current `delete_args()` function above deletes everything in the config.ini. I understand that `delete_args()` needs a way to find the value `[4000, 6000]` in ***config.ini***, so I was wondering if is possible to pass in `[4000, 6000]` as an argument into `delete_args()` that then finds the section `[INPUT]`, and finds the specified interval (`[4000, 6000]`) within `intervals` and deletes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to remove a specific interval from the multi-dimensional list by argument in your `delete_args` function when you update the config.ini. I came up with this solution:

```
import configparser 
import ast

parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
interval = []

def load_args():
    global interval
    parser.read('config.ini')
    interval = ast.literal_eval(parser['INPUT']['intervals'])
    print(interval)

load_args()

def delete_args(index):
    global interval
    interval.pop(index)
    parser.set('INPUT', 'intervals', str(interval))
    with open("config.ini", "w+") as configfile:
        parser.write(configfile)

def delete_args2(ele):
    global interval
    interval = [x for x in interval if x != ele]
    parser.set('INPUT', 'intervals', str(interval))
    with open("config.ini", "w+") as configfile:
        parser.write(configfile)

#delete_args(0)
delete_args2([4000, 6000])

delete_args(0)

load_args()
```

Output

```
[[4000, 6000], [25000, 55000]]
[[25000, 55000]]
```

I used a bit different update strategy, and just `pop()` the element at the specifid index. I think this is a very clean way. If you prefer to pass in a value to remove you can use `interval.remove(ele)` or something more robust like `[x for x in interval if x != ele]` instead of the `pop(index)`.
Note: I've defined `interval` globally for the sake of simplicity but that's not important.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit different approach, but still might work for your purpose. Instead of deleting the `intervals` we may update it as follows:

```
import configparser


def update_args(section, element, value):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    config.set(section, element, value)
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as f:
        config.write(f)


update_args("INPUT", "intervals", "[25000, 55000]")
```

By the way I have just heard about `ini` files here in this question and try to solve this problem. So, I am hoping that I did not something completely unrelated to the question.